# How to check and return data until there are no matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a function, that will search for different tags, tags like [image] and [gallery] inside a JSON file. If there is a match, it will return and replace it with a new output. Like an image object or a slideshow.

A JSON object can contain multiple tags of the same type, or contain different ones at the same time. So an object can contain two [image] tags for e.g.

**JSON**

http://snippi.com/s/bzrx3xi

The problem was, if there are multiple [image] tags found, it was replaced with the same content. I was looking for a script that is searching for the tags, until there will no matches anymore. Many thanks to @debatanu for the solution.

Unfortunately, I have some extra wishes for the script, because now the tags like image, will be replaced for the last image object of the media array inside the JSON and it will only grab and replace the first tag.

I was wondering if it is possible to check each tag and replace each tag with the new output.

**Search for tags**

```
filterText: function(data) {

        // Loop through JSON data
        // Check if [tag] in data.text exists
        var dataText = data.text;
        var tags = {
            "gallery": /\[gallery\]/ig,
            "image": /\[image\]/ig
        };


        if (dataText != undefined) {
            var raw_data = dataText;

            for (var key in tags) {

                if (tags.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var tag = tags[key];
                    var tagArr = [];

                    // Check if [tag] in data.text exists
                    while ( (tagArr = tag.exec(dataText)) !== null ) {

                        // Call functions
                        if (key == "gallery") { 
                            console.error('GALLERY');
                            parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(tagArr[0], shortcodeController.gallery(data));
                            raw_data = parsedHTML;
                            return parsedHTML;
                        }

                        if (key == "image") { 
                            console.error('IMAGE');
                            parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(tagArr[0], shortcodeController.image(data));
                            raw_data = parsedHTML;
                            return parsedHTML;
                            // model.find('p').html(parsedHTML);
                        }

                    }  

                }

            }
        };
```

**Call the filterText function**

```
getDataPopup: function(data) {

        if (data.text != undefined) {
            $('.js-popup .article').html(data.text);
            var parsed = dataController.filterText(data);
            console.log('parsed: ', parsed);
            $('.js-popup .article').html(parsed);
        } else {
            $('.js-popup .article').html(data.intro);
        }

    },
```

Above function will search for tags inside a while loop. 
This script is called, when the user clicked on an item, that will open a popup screen.

The script that is called by the `getDataPopup` function when the user clicked on an item, will search for a match, when there is a match found, it will call the function `shortcodeController.image(data)` that return the new output to the variable: `parsedHTML`.

The function that generates a new output will look like this:

```
image: function(data) {

        // Development
        console.log('shortcodeController.image');

        var raw_data = data.text;
        var outputHTML;

        if (data.media != undefined) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {

                if (data.media[i].image != undefined) {

                    outputHTML = '<div class="image">';

                    // Extract filename
                    var url = data.media[i].image.src;
                    var filename = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.') );
                    // console.log(filename);

                    outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';
                    //data.media[i].image = undefined;

                    outputHTML +='</div>';

                } 

            };

            return outputHTML;

        } else {
            // If media doesn't exists return empty string
            return '';
        }

    },
```

Debatanu has mentioned that I should use `data.media[i].image = undefined;` directly after the outputHTML that contains the actual image object, but this will result in an undefined error. The first [image] tag is replaced by `undefined`. When I comment this line out, it will be replaced by the last image object inside the media array, as mentioned before.

Maybe it does not work like properly, because the while loop, however, only looks for the gallery and image tags and if there is a match,  running it once, because he already saw the tag. Then it will be called again and replaces the first image tag again with the second image object within the media array. Should there might be a while loop added in the if statements on whether it is a gallery or image, so for each tag within the text object is the function called?

Also I noticed, when I console logged `tagArr` it will give me an value of null when I past it after the while loop and a empty array `[]` when I paste it directly after the array is created. Beside that, when I console log tag directly after the while loop is started, it only console log tag once, while there are two image tags set inside the JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exec` and loop through it using

```
    var dataText = data.text;
    var tags = {
        "gallery": /\[gallery\]/ig,
        "image": /\[image\]/ig,
    };

    if (dataText != undefined) {
         var raw_data = dataText;

        for (var key in tags) {
            if (tags.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var tag = tags[key];
                var arr=[];  


         while ((arr= tag.exec(dataText)) !== null) {   
                //arr[0] will contain the first match


                    //var newTag=newTags[key]; 
                    //you need to replace the matched output 
                    //so no need for newTag
                    if (key == "gallery") { 
                        console.error('GALLERY');
                        //replace the matched output arr[0]
                        //instead tag or newTag
                        //Since u have [] to replace we need to ommit the regex literal format /<<exp>>/
                        parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(arr[0], Triptube.shortcodeController.gallery(data));
                       //Need to add this line for reflecting the changed data
                        raw_data=parsedHTML;
                        model.find('p').html(parsedHTML);
                    }

                    if (key == "image") { 
                        console.error('IMAGE');
                        //replace the matched output arr[0]
                        //instead tag or newTag
                        //Since u have [] to replace we need to ommit the regex literal format /<<exp>>/
                        parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(arr[0], Triptube.shortcodeController.image(data));
                        console.log(parsedHTML);
                       //Need to add this line for reflecting the changed data
                        raw_data=parsedHTML;
                        model.find('p').html(parsedHTML);
                    }

                } 
            }
       }
    }
```

You can find more about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)
With each loop the `exec` will give you the next match untill no match is left.

**EDIT**

I have added the entire filter code from the beginning. You see the `raw_data` variable should be assigned before the loop. Once that is done, the code below with the image function should give you the proper result.

**EDIT 2**

First the `filterText` function will return the parsed html post completion of parsing the html

```
   filterText: function(data) {

    // Loop through JSON data
    // Check if [tag] in data.text exists
    var dataText = data.text;
    var tags = {
        "gallery": /\[gallery\]/ig,
        "image": /\[image\]/ig
    };


    if (dataText != undefined) {
        var raw_data = dataText,
        newData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));//Copy of the data object

        for (var key in tags) {

            if (tags.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var tag = tags[key];
                var tagArr = [];

                // Check if [tag] in data.text exists
                while ( (tagArr = tag.exec(dataText)) !== null ) {

                    // Call functions
                    if (key == "gallery") { 
                        console.error('GALLERY');
                        parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(tagArr[0], shortcodeController.gallery(newData));
                        raw_data = parsedHTML;
                        //return parsedHTML;
                    }

                    if (key == "image") { 
                        console.error('IMAGE');
                        parsedHTML = raw_data.replace(tagArr[0], shortcodeController.image(newData));
                        raw_data = parsedHTML;
                        //return parsedHTML; we will return the parsed HTML only when all the tags have been replaced
                        // model.find('p').html(parsedHTML);
                    }

                }  

            }

        }
       return parsedHTML; //return the parsed HTML here
    };
```

Next is the `image` function which will parse through the images,

```
      image: function(data) {

    // Development
    console.log('shortcodeController.image');

    var raw_data = data.text;
    var outputHTML;

    if (data.media != undefined) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.media.length; i++) {

            if (data.media[i].image != undefined) {

                outputHTML = '<div class="image">';

                // Extract filename
                var url = data.media[i].image.src;
                var filename = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.') );
                // console.log(filename);

                outputHTML += '<img src="' + url + '" alt="' + filename + '" />';
                outputHTML +='</div>';
                data.media[i].image = undefined;
                //Uncommented the above code, because now the operation will be done on the copy of the original data object



            } 

        };

        return outputHTML;

    } else {
        // If media doesn't exists return empty string
        return '';
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use a regex literal instead of the `tag` variable it will result in an infinite loop. Did you try using it? MDN gives a rather elaborate example.

Comment: I look at the code, but arr will not be filled right? In above code, newTag will filled with newTag or does I have it wrong?

Comment: Actually when there is a match the match is returned as an array so if there is a match the `arr` will be populated with the data if not it will return null and will come out of the while loop. The `newTags` is not needed, you can use the match `arr[0]` to directly use for replace.

Comment: It doesn't replace the tag, while using `/arr[0]/`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have changed the regex literal term `/arr[0]/` to `arr[0]` to include the `[`,`]` while searching.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your code above, but it does only replace the first match for image or gallery. If there are multiple `[image]` or `[gallery]` it will only replace the first tag, not the other ones. It should look for all tags inside the text and replace them all, also if the text contains different tags inside one text object. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is because the `raw_data` variable was getting re-assigned with the `dataText` value everytime in the start of the loop. Sorry for not noticing it before. I have edited the code, and added one more line `raw_data=parsedHTML` to retain the changes in the `raw_data` variable.

Comment: No problem, but unfortunately it's still not working. My filter function looks like this: http://snippi.com/s/gt4c5lx I call this function, when the user clicked on a item: http://snippi.com/s/jiqowlb This function is called in the init, while the page is loaded. Hope we can solve this :) So the first code is the filter, the second link will show how I call this function when the user clicks on the popup and call the function, that will return the new output.

Comment: Good to add is the function that will generate an image object to replace the `[image]`. http://snippi.com/s/2c4ty07 Hope you get a better view of what the code looks like currently.

Comment: I am hoping that in the `image` function `data.media` contains the images to be replaced inside your filter function. I have modified the image function http://snippi.com/s/iutxg95

Comment: Yes, media contains all the media types that are used inside the text object. I tried your changes, it will replace only the first [image] tag (as before) but now it will be replaced with the last image object in the array of image objects..

Comment: Your code works fine, the only thing is that I keep on messing up the placement of the `raw_data` variable. I have edited the answer and added the entire filter function, with the proper placement of the `raw_data` variable.

Comment: Same as before. I copy past your update below, including the snippi, but still only the first image tag will be replaced, with the last object in the array of media. JSON looks like this: http://snippi.com/s/70jcys8

Comment: The change in the filterText parameter is not the same as for me, also my fault for not mention, but I have multiple objects in my JSON. So data.content[0] will only grab the first object. I spit out my function that handles the image object. The problem is that the return function will only be fired once, so it will only return the first image object for replacing the first image tag. When I comment out that line, the loop will loop through all image objects within the array of media. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The `image` function will be fired once for every match. Say for example you have two `[image]` tags, for each match when you call the `image` function the you are doing a check whether the `data.media.image` is `undefined`, if not the function goes ahead with the data extraction. Inside the data extraction part just before `return outputHTML;` in the snippet above i had added `data.media[i].image=undefined;`. Hence, everytime this function is called it will give you the next `image object` with content in the `media` array. u can pass the `data.content[0],content[1],` so on to filter func.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get stuck with the code. I copy/paste your code and it still not working as expect. I think I do something wrong, or does not describe it clear enough.. To prevent and save your many questions misunderstandings I've updated my question that hopefully provides greater clarity on exactly what is still not fully satisfactory.

Comment: Can you check once the EDIT2? I have modifed the code.